# Printing after a break in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

I'm trying to figure out how to print the final line of code for this - whether it's a prime number or not. I can't seem to get it to print with the code I have. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive number to test: "))

while number <= 0:
    print ("Sorry, only positive numbers. Try again.")
    number = int(input("Enter a positive number to test: "))

test = 2

number1 = number - 1
for x in range (0, number1):
    trial = number % test
    if trial != 0:
        print (test, "is NOT a divisor of", number, "...")
        break
        print (number, "is a prime number!")
    else:
        print (test, "is a divisor of", number, "...")
        break
        print (number, "is not a prime number!")
    test = test + 1
```

Comment: The `print` statement after `break` is unreachable.

Comment: You cannot decide  whether a number is prime (with your algorithm) before you have run the whole loop (= tested all numbers) or found a factor. Consequently those two print statements have to be somewhere else. I would suggest the 'else' statement of the for loop that gets executed. You also cannot 'break' when trial != 0, because that means that your loop stops there and does not continue on looking for factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement ends the execution of the branch. The following `print` statement is never reached.

To get the correct functionaility use a boolean value and perform the check at the end:

```
is_prime = True

for x in range (2, number):
    trial = number % x
    if trial != 0:
        print (x, "is NOT a divisor of", number, "...")
    else:
        is_prime = False
        print (x, "is a divisor of", number, "...")

if is_prime:
    print (number, "is a prime number!")
else:
    print (number, "is not a prime number!")
```

You also do not need to use a variable `test`. Use the `x` from your range directly.

Have a look at the [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) for the keyword for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
if expression:

    statement(s)

else:

    statement(s)
```

It executes all statements with **break** so **print** will be never happen...